# How to access graphql field name in nestjs?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

Im trying to access to the name value of the field decorator in the following input.

```
//myInput.ts

@InputType()
export class MyInput {
  @Field(() => Int, { name: "price" })
  priceValue: number;
}
```

```
//myResolver.ts

@Resolver()
export class MyResolver {
  constructor(private readonly myService: MyService){}

  @Query(() => boolean)
  async prices(@Args('input') input: MyInput){
    /*
      So in typescript system the input field is named `priceValue` but in the
      graphql side is named `price` (This is the string i want to access)
    */
  }

}
```

I try various things like with `@Info()` decorator and with `TypeMetadaStorage` but i couldn't find the renaming value.

Is there any workaround to access this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a way with TypeMetadataStorage method getArgumentsMetadataByTarget(MyInput);

```
  const schemaNames = TypeMetadataStorage.getArgumentsMetadataByTarget(MyInput).properties.map(({ schemaName }) => schemaName);
```